# How to find out where TYPO3 cookies are set?

Tags: typo3, session-cookies, typo3-10.x, typo3-form

I have two different installations of TYPO3 10.4.27 and try to remove all cookies.

I wonder why on one site having a contact-form, the fe_typo_user cookie is set and on the other site with the exact same form.yaml definition, it isn't set a cookie.

Additionally, I have a page, where a be_typo_user is set, without me doing this intentionally. - Edit: I found this one in my own code. Instantiated "BackendUserAuthentication"

It seems to be "normal" to have the fe_typo3_user cookie set on pages with forms. When I delete it once and reload the page it depends on the Typoscript setting config.no_cache whether the cookies are set again or not. With config.no_cache = 0, the cookies won't be set again. With config.no_cache = 1 (which you shouldn't be set) the cookies come again and again while doing "delete cookies => reload page". So I recognized, that with a "fresh" browser visiting the site I previously saw no cookie, there is one, too.

I can reproduce this behavior on any typo3 v9/v10 site on a page with a form by deleting frontend cache and loading it with another browser afterwards.

Can I get rid of those cookies? Are they DSGVO relevant for sites without cookie banner?

Comment: Can you specify the _exact_ TYPO3 version you use here? Notice that the domains have been replaced with examples since this could be security-relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the advices. I replaced the domains with the exact TYPO3 versions.

Comment: Tested with same form.yaml definition.

Comment: Tested with same TYPO3 version (10.4.27)

Comment: OK, then you definitely do not use an outdated version.

Answer (score 0):

On the one site with cookies I had config.no_cache = 1 (which you shouldn't be set), the other had the default value config.no_cache = 0.

I additionally tested it with two browsers.

1. Clear Frontend Cache
2. Hit the page with form in one browser getting cookie set
3. Hit the same page in another browser getting no cookie